# correct place for my form tag to pass correct value in action PROBLEM

Tags: php, html

i have this code:

```
<body>
<div class="header">
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !isset($menu)) { ?>
    <div class="menu_holder">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo ADDRESS; ?>menu.php" class="green_link">
                    <img src="<?php echo IMAGES; ?>template/menu.gif" width="51" height="20" border="0" />
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php
            if (!isset($plainHeader))
            {
                    $plainHeader = "&nbsp;";
    ?>
            <img src="<?php echo IMAGES; ?>template/logo.gif" width="160" height="94" />
    <?php
            }
    ?>
</div>

<br/>&nbsp;
<?php $id_to = $user['profile_id_contact']; ?>
<div class="main_content">
<center>
<div class="innerContainer">
   <span class="headings2">FREE CHAT CONTACTS</span>
   <form id="message_area" style="display:none"  method="post" action="<?php echo ADDRESS; ?>messageSent.php?id=<?php echo $id_to ?>">
       <?php
            if (count($users) > 0)
            {
                foreach ($users as $user)
                {
                    //some php here
                ?>
               <a href="#" class="charcoal_link" style="line-height: 20px;" onclick="showMessageArea(this); return false;" >
                 <?php echo $uniqueCode1?><span class="pink_text"><?php echo $uniqueCode2?></span><?php echo $uniqueCode3?>
               </a>                                      
               <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
               <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send"></input>
               <?php
                }
            }  
       ?> 
  </form>
</div>
</center>
</div>
</body>
```

as my code is now the form tag is in the wrong place because my  tag links does not show.
where must i put my form tag so that when i click on any of the uniquecode links i pass the correct $id_to in the action??? when i move the form tag after the  my links show but regardless of which link i click on it passes the first link's $id_to with the action. i have also tried to pass $id_to as a hidden field which i had after the sumbit but still it passes the first link's id

please help? i have been struggeling with this for some time now...i cannot redirect the page via JS becuase this site is for a MOBILE aka mobi site

please help? im desperate
thank you

if i move the form tag and have it like this: 
    
      
    
    messageSent.php?id=">

and i view the page source $id_to contains correct id but as sson as i go to sentMessage.php the id in the url is incorrect

Comment: what does showMessageArea() do?

Comment: if i move the form tag and have it like this: 
    <a href="#" class="charcoal_link" style="line-height: 20px;" onclick="showMessageArea(this); return false;" >
     <?php echo $uniqueCode1?><span class="pink_text"><?php echo $uniqueCode2?></span><?php echo $uniqueCode3?>
   </a>      
   <form id="message_area" style="display:none"  method="post" action="<?php echo ADDRESS; ?>messageSent.php?id=<?php echo $id_to ?>">                                
      <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
      <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send"></input>
    </form>

Comment: and i view page source $id_to is correct but as soon as the action redirects $id_to contains the first link's id!! i dont understand

Comment: here is the JS:
   function showMessageArea(link)
   {
      var message_area = document.getElementById('message_area');
      message_area.parentNode.removeChild(message_area);
      link.parentNode.insertBefore(message_area, link.nextSibling);
      message_area.style.display="block";
   }

Comment: please add your comment in your question instead its impossible to read it here. click on edit in ur question

Answer (score 0):

To pass a id to the next page in a link you need to add "?id='.$id.'" at the end of the url.

e.g.

```
<a href="<?php echo ADDRESS; ?>menu.php?id=5" class="charcoal_link" style="line-height: 20px;">
```

To make sure that each link is different you can right click and copy the url to double check.

Comment: i tried that and it does NOT go to my sentMessage.php then and yes i copy and paste the url i get from view page source and it is correct

Comment: have you copied that url with "?id=5" in your browser's address bar to see if that worked?